# Forecasting method used for predicting the date of some events

Tags: forecasting

If i'm working in a car company and I have some data for every customer i.e.

- Their license plate
- Date of their car's service in the dealer
- Number of km in their car when they service it
- Their periodic service (e.g. 1000 km, 2000 km, etc.)

Can we predict when will the customer back to the dealer to service their car again? Can we use forecasting method to predict the exact date?

Comment: Probably not directly for the date. But you could recast your data as number of days until service, fit a model of that as a function of covariates, and transform the prediction back into a date.

Comment: What type of forecasting method i can use? i mean like ARIMA, calendar variation, etc. what kind of method i can use for that case?

Comment: That is a much broader question. Start with something simple, like linear regression. More complex methods aren't always better.

Comment: Okay i see, thank you very much for your answer :)